# Bootstrap 3 push-pull classes create a gap in my layout

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3.1.1. I have a layout in which I would like to have the secondary menu pull to the left on larger screens. However, using push/pull classes leave a gap in the layout.

The mobile view works correctly, like this:

```
------------
|  Banner   |
------------
|  Menu     |
------------
|  Heading  |
------------
|  Content  |
------------
```

However, in desktop view, this happens:

```
--------   ------------
| Menu |   | Banner   |
| Menu |  ------------
| Menu |
| Menu | 
--------
          ------------
          | Heading   |
          ------------
          | Content   |
          ------------
```

This result is essentially correct, except for the large gap between the banner and the heading. The heading (and content that follows) should be beside the menu and under the banner. Below the menu should stay whitespace (I don't wish to wrap any of the blocks).

I've tried using simply pull-right and pull-left, but that messed up my mobile view.

Markup (simplified):

```
<section id="banner-content" class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">
    <h1>Banner Content</h1>
</section>
<section id="menu" class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">
    <h3>Menu Title</h3>
    <ul role="navigation">
        <li>Menu Item with Link</li>
        <li>Menu Item With Link</li>
        <li>Menu Item With Link</li>
    </ul>
</section>
<section id="heading" class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">
     <h2>Secondary Page Title</h2>
</section>
<section id="contentwrapper" class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">
     <p>Content here</p>
</section>
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c52jxde8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the push and pull grid styles. You simply need to pull the three items to the right of the navigation when it reaches a certain point.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d8bwsh2o/)**

**HTML**:

```
<div id="Banner" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 pull-right">
     Banner Content
</div>
<div id="Navigation" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
     Menu Title

    <ul role="navigation">
        <li>Menu Item with Link</li>
        <li>Menu Item With Link</li>
        <li>Menu Item With Link</li>
        <li>Menu Item With Link</li>
        <li>Menu Item With Link</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="Title" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 pull-right">
     Secondary Page Title
</div>
<div id="Content" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 pull-right">
    Content here
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div {
    color:white;
}
#Banner {
    background:red;
    height:50px;
}
#Navigation {
    background:green;
    height:150px;
}
#Title {
    background:blue;
    height:50px;
}
#Content {
    background:orange;
    height:50px;
}
```

As you can see, when you hit the mobile width the banner goes above your navigation with the rest of the content bellow it, but on small screens and larger it pulls them all to the right of the navigation div. The CSS is simply for styling, you can adjust it to meet your needs.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I didn't think to use the -xs classes when my mobile view got smushed up when using pulls. Your answer works perfectly.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if, in the markup, I were to place the menu below the heading so that semantically the H2 heading would occur before the H3 on the menu, how would I place the menu at the top of the left column? If I keep the classes as they are, the menu goes beside the heading but has a gap at the top beside the banner. Just wondering if it is possible. Thanks.

Comment: Not entirely sure, having trouble visualizing it in my mind, but it's considered best practice here to tinker with things on your own, and ask new questions instead of different questions as comments on existing ones. ;)

Comment: Oh sorry, thanks for the tip. Your answer works great anyway; I have used it as a starting point.